# How do I convert this tSQL statement to LINQ using group by in a sub query

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, t-sql

I have the following MSSQL query I am trying to convert to LINQ. I am using entity framework with the following syntax to get at the data.

```
var rv = (from i in DC.TableA select i).ToList();
```

This is the sql I want to write a C# LINQ query for but I cannot figure it out. Can someone help?

```
select BTO.* 
from TableA BTO 
join 
(
    select eqnum, max(testdate) as testdate  
    from TableA BTO1
    where 
        BTO1.eqnum in ('M0435', 'Z0843') and 
        BTO1.testdate <= '2008-06-01' 
    group by eqnum 
) T1 
on 
    T1.eqnum = BTO.eqnum and 
    T1.testdate = BTO.testdate 
    order by EqNum;
```

Comment: are you familiar with a tool called `LinqPad`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is opportunity to rewrite your query, but for information purposes I rewrote your `sql` into `linq` verbatim.

If you explain what you are trying to achieve we can provide alternative `sql` / `linq`

```
var eqnums = new[] { "M0435", "Z0843" };
var testdate = "2008-06-01";

var query = from bto in DC.TableA
            join t1 in (
               from bto1 in DC.TableA
               where eqnums.Contains(bto1.eqnum) &&
                  bto1.testdate.CompareTo(testdate) <= 0
               group bto1 by bto1.eqnum into g
               select new 
               {
                  eqnum = g.Key,
                  testdate  = g.Max(x => x.testdate)
               }
            ) on new { bto.eqnum, bto.testdate } equals new { t1.eqnum, t1.testdate }
            orderby bto.eqnum
            select bto;
```

Comment: One issue with this reply is that testdate in the DB is actually a string, and not a proper datetime datatype. MSSQL handles the max(testdate) and the <= '2008-06-01' correctly as the column is formatted in 'yyyy-MM-dd' and the range operand '<=' works as is. Since I do not have the ability to change this on the database, and I don't want to return all the data and convert it in memory on the client, and I have close to 30 million rows, I want to execute this on the sql side and return as miminal data over the wire as possible.

Comment: The query as I posted it is working very efficiently and only returning rows I need. Since the datatype on the DB is a string and not a date time data type, the max functions and such on the LINQ side fail and I am left twiddling my thumbs on how to achieve this.

Comment: @KarlEasterly - I didn't realize `testdate` was a `varchar`. Using `CompareTo` should work. Take a look at my update

Comment: There are ~20 thousand rows for each eqnum, testdate pair, and I need the closest eqnum, testdate set prior to the filter date. Each eqnum object has many sets of testdate, with each testdate having many rows with that same testdate.

Comment: @KarlEasterly - The `linq` query should be exactly what your `sql` query is doing. If you are not getting the same results, post example results of your `sql` query and `linq` query in your question